# Tensorflow failed to create a newwriteablefile when retraining inception

Tags: python, windows, machine-learning, tensorflow, python-3.5

I am following this tutorial: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/?utm_campaign=chrome_series_machinelearning_063016&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=yt-desc#4

I am running this part of the code:

```
python retrain.py \
  --bottleneck_dir=bottlenecks \
  --how_many_training_steps=500 \
  --model_dir=inception \
  --summaries_dir=training_summaries/basic \
  --output_graph=retrained_graph.pb \
  --output_labels=retrained_labels.txt \
  --image_dir=flower_photos
```

Here is the error that I get after it finds the images, makes a bunch of bottlenecks and also does steps training.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "retrain.py", line 1062, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "retrain.py", line 905, in main
    f.write('\n'.join(image_lists.keys()) + '\n')
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 101, in write
    self._prewrite_check()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 87, in _prewrite_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), compat.as_bytes(self.__mode), status)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Failed to create a NewWriteableFile: /tmp/output_labels.txt : The system cannot find the path specified.
```

You can find all my code here:
https://github.com/officialgupta/MachineLearningRecipes

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I have also found some similar errors. And if I understood, that you need to set an absolute paths for `--output_graph` and `--output_labels`.

For example:

```
--output_graph=/home/%your_homhttps://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/17020426#e_user_name_folder%/Inception_retrained_graph.pb 
--output_labels=/home/%your_home_user_name_folder%/Inception_retrained_labels.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. The only thing I had to do is to reduce the length of path.

For example:

`C:\Users\test\lib\Workspace\DataScience\Bachelorarbeit\ba_test\src\saved_models\neural20201029-235456-a0.8775`

instead of

`C:\Users\test\lib\Workspace\DataScience\Bachelorarbeit\ba_test\src\saved_models\neural20201029-234822Arg-e1-b512-l1-n256-oadam-z0.005-r0-d0-a0.8803`.

Comment: How do you reduce the path name?

Comment: As you can see in my example, I have used a shorter name for the saved model: ``neural20201029-235456-a0.8775`` instead of ``neural20201029-234822Arg-e1-b512-l1-n256-oadam-z0.005-r0-d0-a0.8803``

Comment: Hi, I can see that you have changed it, but I am interested how?

In the link is my original problem, how would you change location here?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65974699/keras-hyperparameter-autotune-notfounderror

Comment: I use the ``model.save(path)`` method in Keras. Therefore, I have to pass a path parameter which I can modify in the mentioned way.

Comment: Is there any logic behind how you selected the name of the path

Comment: No not really, first I have used different hyperparameters in the name to distinguish between the saved models but they are not necessary, so I deleted them to reduce the path length.

Answer (score 2):

In a similar case,I have met errors, when I tried to execute this command:

```
writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)
```

then I found that, the output_path is empty. So you need to make sure an absolute paths is available.

Comment: does not work on tf 2.6.0

Answer (score 0):

I might be late for giving an answer but putting up an answer and hoping that it will be useful for anyone facing similar issue.

Today I came across similar issue while retraining the Inception model on Tensorflow and followed some steps to correct it.

There are two things we need to take care of.

1. Activate tensorflow before using Tensorflow commands.

   **source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate**
2. Use full path of the files mentioned in your terminal commands as answered by @Nikita Verbitskiy in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

try below command in win10 to solve the problem

```
python -m retrain 
--bottleneck_dir=bottlenecks
--how_many_training_steps=500 
--model_dir=models 
--summaries_dir=tf_files 
--output_graph=retrained.pb 
--output_labels=retrained_labels.txt 
--architecture="mobilenet_0.50_224" 
--image_dir=flower_photos
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit why this is a solution? Also, you can use ` ` around code to make it look like `code`.

Answer (score 0):

> I faced the same problem, and could fix it.

Just to clear some things up, my code is running without ..

- setting an absolute path
- activating tensorflow

On the first run everything was saved as expected, on the second run I had the same issue as described.

For me it was enough to not set

```
--save_model_dir
```

but only setting

```
--output_labels
--output_graph
```