# Python(anaconda) The system cannot find the path specified. ; No such process [Op:SaveV2]

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, anaconda, mask

I'm trying to train a model for mask detection from this tutorial:

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOI0o3Cxv9Q&feature=youtu.be)

and when I run the model training code on anaconda prompt:

```
python Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py--model_dir=Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet--pipeline_config_path=Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet/pipeline.config--num_train_steps=4500
```

I get this error as the final result:

```
\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Failed to create a NewWriteableFile: Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet\ckpt-1_temp_5d6be93f474340519c0fe8ec2683d403/part-00000-of-00001.data-00000-of-00001.tempstate9043543319781776398 : 
The system cannot find the path specified.
; No such process [Op:SaveV2]
```

It looks like it is related to multiple files because it gives me errors in different files from different directories.

This is the full error code:

```
2020-12-26 05:19:51.521080: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1767] OP_REQUIRES failed at save_restore_v2_ops.cc:109 : Not found: Failed to create a NewWriteableFile: Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet\ckpt-1_temp_5d6be93f474340519c0fe8ec2683d403/part-00000-of-00001.data-00000-of-00001.tempstate9043543319781776398 : The system cannot find the path specified.
; No such process

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py", line 113, in <module>
tf.compat.v1.app.run()

File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
_run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)

File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 303, in run
_run_main(main, args)

File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
sys.exit(main(argv))

File "Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py", line 104, in main
model_lib_v2.train_loop(

File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 627, in train_loop
manager.save()

File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\checkpoint_management.py", line 807, in save
save_path = self._checkpoint.write(prefix)

File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\util.py", line 1898, in write
output = self._saver.save(file_prefix=file_prefix, options=options)

File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\util.py", line 1199, in save
save_path, new_feed_additions = self._save_cached_when_graph_building(

File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\util.py", line 1145, in _save_cached_when_graph_building
save_op = saver.save(file_prefix, options=options)

 File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saving\functional_saver.py", line 295, in save
return save_fn()

File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saving\functional_saver.py", line 269, in save_fn
sharded_saves.append(saver.save(shard_prefix, options))

File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saving\functional_saver.py", line 78, in save
return io_ops.save_v2(file_prefix, tensor_names, tensor_slices, tensors)

File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_io_ops.py", line 1728, in save_v2
return save_v2_eager_fallback(

File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_io_ops.py", line 1749, in save_v2_eager_fallback
_result = _execute.execute(b"SaveV2", 0, inputs=_inputs_flat, attrs=_attrs,

File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Failed to create a NewWriteableFile: Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet\ckpt-1_temp_5d6be93f474340519c0fe8ec2683d403/part-00000-of-00001.data-00000-of-00001.tempstate9043543319781776398 : The system cannot find the path specified.
; No such process [Op:SaveV2]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45076911/tensorflow-failed-to-create-a-newwriteablefile-when-retraining-inception

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the format of your paths: instead of "\" use "/"